# Magento ver. 2.4.5-p1 gives error An error occurred while parsing the XML request. This is the result of an XML parser error. during invoice generate

Tags: magento, magento2

When i try to capture card from admin invoice at that time i am getting bellow error

error : An error occurred while parsing the XML request. This is the result of an XML parser error.

screen-shot : https://nimb.ws/GXvcgh

so please let me know how can i resolve this error. and how can i get actual file error.

Thanks

i have tired to check all log and try to find files from which this error coming but not found actual file path

Comment: How can we provide solution without looking at code?..please provide the code

Comment: default magento we have this issue is not from my custom code

Comment: ok..posted a answer for you..try that if it works..

Answer (score 0):

Delete Generated folder from Magento Root Directory and run following command:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

after that

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```